# Custom WebKit scrollbars reverting to original scrollbar

Tags: html, css, webkit

I asked a question similar to this earlier, but it wasn't very descriptive. I deleted that question and I'm going to re-ask it.

So, on my website, I'd like to have a custom scrollbar. It works fine, except for when my site has too many linebreaks. Here's my CSS code for the scrollbars:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              
{width:10px;
height:10px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       
{display:none;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        
{background-color:#DDDDDD;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  
{background-color:#DDDDDD;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       
{background-color:#DDDDDD;}
::-webkit-resizer                
{background-color:#DDDDDD;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        
{background-color:#666666}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover        
{background-color:#999999}
```

It's hard to explain. If there's too much page to scroll, it's not going to show up properly. It will revert to the default scrolling bar. I'm wondering if this is just happening on my side, or is this an actual issue? And if it's just happening to me, what am I doing wrong?

I've just tried it on JSFiddle, and it's working fine. I can put as many linebreaks as I want, it will not break the scrollbar. What's wrong? [Here's the website where it doesn't work.](http://hexagonest.tk) If you look in the source code, the style is all right. It's the same as the fiddle, but less linebreaks. [Here's the fiddle, it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/3EdNE/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Chromium 31.0.1650.63. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @CarloCannas I'm using Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63.

Comment: Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Ubuntu, still can't reproduce. I even tried to resize the window, still the scrollbar is the custom one. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @CarloCannas Windows 7 Ultimate. Did you go to http://www.hexagonest.tk?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't believe me I'll make you a screenshot. Unfortunately I can't test it on Windows 7, but on Windows 8 still there is no problem showing up (Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m).

Comment: @CarloCannas Try it again now, I added a line break.

EDIT: Here's what I see http://puu.sh/6hSND.png

Comment: Oh, I can reproduce it now. Well, I'm going into debugging mode.

Comment: @CarloCannas Yeah, for some reason I didn't have the line break that would break it. Let me know, please.

Comment: Really, really strange: it seems to happen only if there is a `input password` element in a `form`, all other elements are irrelevant. Also, depending on how do you resize the window, the custom scrollbar shows up. This happens also on Opera, so it must be a WebKit bug.

Comment: @CarloCannas is there anywhere I can report this bug?

Comment: Just letting you know, it displays fine for me on Fedora Chrome 30.0.1599.114

Comment: @Imaginate Yeah, I changed it back.